# What effect does a bitwise AND have when comparing bit sums?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I have a decision tree that uses bit sums to determine branching.

For example:
If we have rules: 1,2,4,8,16
the sum is determined by: if true then sum += ruleId.

The branching function, rather than do:

```
if(sum == 23) =>
else if(sum == 15) =>
```

Uses a bitwise AND:

```
if(sum & 23 == 23) =>
else if(sum & 15 == 15) =>
```

What is the difference between using the bitwise AND and the == ?

What I need to do is generate a `List<Tuple<int,boo>>` that will lead a given outcome to evaluate true. My thinking was to do:
For 23, for example:

```
1 && 2 && 4 && 8 && !16
```

Will cause it to evaluate to true. However, what impact does the bitwise AND have on this? What do I need to change to correctly output the expression(s) that will lead it to be true?

Comment: Note that `&&` only works with `bool`.

Comment: @DrewJordan - I thought I said `|` was addition. I might have just mistyped. Anyway comment deleted.

Comment: I suggest you explain more about your requirements. You say you have a set of rules. So if the requirement to execute each rule if it has been chosen. So for `23` you would execute rules 1, 2, 4 and 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use bitwise operations at all? In the specific case that you mentioned, it won't matter (as long as you wrap the AND in parens like [musefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35136198/3845456) mentions).

But, what happens if something is slightly different? For example, if a new developer comes along later and has to add a case, and doesn't understand how it works. They add the next bit (32, or 100000) and add their check to the *bottom* of the `if`s:

```
if((sum & 23) == 23) =>
else if((sum & 15) == 15) =>
//...
else if((sum & 31) == 31) =>
```

What happens?

Well, 31 in binary & (bitwise AND) 23 in binary:

```
11111
10111
-----
10111
```

Uh oh! that evaluates to true! And since they, not knowing any better, added it to the bottom, 23 evaluates to TRUE first and 31 never gets evaluated.

So, it becomes a question of your intention. If that's expected behavior (I doubt it) then you can use bitwise ops, and you'll always know that if you're checking against, for example, 23, you're checking that those specific bits are set, and NOT that they are the only bits set. If you want to know whether ONLY all of the bits in 23 are set, use (sum == 23).

Comment: I like this answer, it has my name in it... also its a good point about ensuring it it doing what it is supposed to. If I was guessing at intentions I would lean towards that is should be a series of `if` statements (without `else`). So, if this rule has been set then execute it, and repeat for each rule

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between using the bitwise AND and the == ?

Well `==` checks to see if the two values are equal, simple. Bitwise AND calculates a value where the bits match. When this is combined with the equals check then you are effectively checking if `sum` has the same bits set as `23` uses.

Easier to understand if you write the bits down, lets say `sum = 31`:

```
  0001 1111 // (sum 31)
& 0001 0111 // (23)
= 0001 0111 // (only set 1 if *both* are 1)
```

Notice you end up with the same as `23` so when you do `(sum & 23) == 23` you get `true`. The purpose of this is to check if specific bits are set. In the case of `23` you are checking if bits 16, 4, 2 and 1 are set.

`"C# Bit Flags"` is a useful search term if you want to find out more information.

Note, you *need* to use brackets around the bitwise AND as the order of precedence will try to evaluate the `==` first:

```
if((sum & 23) == 23)
```

---

This is purely guessing at what you might be trying to acheive, but if you are trying to execute each rule that has been set then you might want something like this:

```
if((sum & 1) == 1)
    ExecuteRule1();
if((sum & 2) == 2)
    ExecuteRule2();
if((sum & 4) == 4)
    ExecuteRule4();
if((sum & 8) == 8)
    ExecuteRule8();
if((sum & 16) == 16)
    ExecuteRule16();
```

With this code, in the case of `sum = 23` it will execute rules 1, 2, 4 and 16. But will skip rule 8.

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator is going to be true only if the sum equals the value that you're testing against. The bitwise && check will make sure that all of the bits represented by that number are set in your value.

For example

sum = 23 (10111), then sum == 23 will be true, as will sum & 23 == 23.

sum = 25 (11001), then sum == 23 will be false, but sum & 23 now returns 17.

```
  11001
& 10111
 ======
  10001 (17)
```

Comment: You would be better off finding an example where `sum & 23` is `23`. As then you can see how one can be false while the other is true

Answer (score 0):

You need a further comparison (like ==) when you have multiple bits being selected. Thus

```
if (sum & 020)
```

Selects exactly one bit. Either it's on or it's off.

```
if (sum & 017)
```

Selects the last four bits, but will evaluate to true if any of those bits are set.

```
if ((sum & 017) == 017)
```

Selects the last four bits, and all bits must be set for the expression to be true.

However, none of these tests look at other bits that may be set. If you want to assert that some bits are set and others are not, you get more complicated tests:

```
if ((sum & 017) == 017 && !(sum & 060))
```

At some point, you cross over to where it is a clearer expression of your intent to do an equality comparison than a bit mask.

BTW, you will note that I am using octal constants.
Octal or decimal are easier to use and maintain for bit masking (IMO).

Comment: I think your example are very confusing in trying to explain it. Also I don't think `Selects the last four bits, but will evaluate to true if any of those bits are set` is correct. All four bits need to be set for it to be true, not *any* of them

Comment: Not so. As an example, `022 & 017` evaluates to 02, which is non-zero, so `if (022 & 017)` will evaluate true.

Comment: Sorry, I though that comment was referring to the `if ((sum & 017) == 017)` code. If we are talking about your first 2 example then it's irrelevant, as they won't even compile